# Docker and Django Postgresql issue

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I am currently learning how to implement docker with Django and Postgres DB. Everytime I tried I run the following command:

```
docker compose up --build -d --remove-orphans
```

Although I can see all my images are started. Every time I tried to open my Django admin site, I cannot sign in using already registered superuser credentials. In Postgres DB PGAdmin all the data that are created previously are stored and saved correctly. But after closing my computer an I start Docker compose up previously saved data's are not recognized by the new start up even if the data still visible in my Postgres DB. How can I make the data to be recognized at start up?
Here is my docker-compose.yml configurations:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/local/django/Dockerfile
        # ports:
        #     - "8000:8000"
        command: /start
        
        volumes:
           - .:/app
           - ./staticfiles:/app/staticfiles
           - ./mediafiles:/app/mediafiles
        expose:
            - "8000"
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - postgres-db
            - redis
        networks:
            - estate-react

    client:
        build:
            context: ./client
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
            - ./client:/app
            - /app/node_modules
        networks:
            - estate-react
    postgres-db:
        image: postgres:12.0-alpine
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
        networks:
            - estate-react
        
    redis:
        image: redis:5-alpine
        networks:
            - estate-react
    celery_worker:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/local/django/Dockerfile
        command: /start-celeryworker
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - postgres-db
        networks:
            - estate-react
    
    flower:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/local/django/Dockerfile
        command: /start-flower
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        env_file:
            - .env
        ports:
            - "5557:5555"
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - postgres-db
        networks:
            - estate-react

    nginx:
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - api
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
            - media_volume:/app/mediafiles
        build: 
            context: ./docker/local/nginx
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        networks:
            - estate-react


networks:
    estate-react:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    postgres_data:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:
```

Here is Docker nginx default.conf file setup:

```
upstream api {
    server api:8000;
}

upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

server {
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    listen 80;

    location /api/v1 {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /app/mediafiles/;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://client;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }
    
}
```

Your answer is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: is it possible that your pgadmin looks at a different database? maybe one running on host? do you still see data after `docker-compose down`? what your describe is very strange and it doesn't look like a docker issue. Also, how does your app connect to the database? what is the connection string?

Comment: The database configuration in my splitted setting.py is as follows: ``` DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": env("POSTGRES_ENGINE"),
        "NAME": env("POSTGRES_DB"),
        "USER": env("POSTGRES_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": env("PG_HOST"),
        "PORT": env("PG_PORT"),
    }
}```  Furthermore in my .env file this is the configuration: ```POSTGRES_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
POSTGRES_USER=*****
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=****
POSTGRES_DB=estate
# PG_HOST=localhost
PG_HOST = postgres-db
PG_PORT=5432  ```

Comment: When I test the API endpoints, the data will be saved correctly inside my Postgres DB. When I run the endpoints from frontend, It display 200 ok but it shows null data despite the fact that There is still data available inside Postgres DB. The problem arises when I ran all my Django files, react and Nginx from docker. Without closing my computer everything works fine. However the next day when I run docker compose up, All the data that are saved from the previous day are not recognized. It will start as if there is no data. However the application starts correctly from the proxy 8080 port.